# How to calculate estimated date by the number of months user insert?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-calendar

I'm making an app that will calculate a date between the current phone date and a new date that depends on user input.

> Example: newDate = current(20/5) + months(3)
>
> So newDate should be 20/8.

And I need a way to store newDate into my database too. Please help it's for my failing final year project T.T

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`Calendar`** class to do your job,

How? check out below,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
cal.setTime(currentDate); // pass your current Date class instance
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 3); // Now use this calendar to add 3 months to add in your current date.
cal.getTime(); // Now get date of 3 months after
```

Comment: @Lola, consider accepting answer if it helps.

Comment: How to save the newdate into db? Like where should I put it and all

Comment: You can store milliseconds from new date to database